# Webbrowser не правильно отображает HTML документ,в чем может быть причина?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser, кодировка

В разметке определил webbrowser

```
<WebBrowser Language="" Name="WebBroserForShowMessage" local:WebBrowserExtentions.Document="{Binding Messages/Text}" />
```

Свойству Messages/Text присвоено следующее значение

```
<div dir=\"ltr\">ав</div>\r\n
```

а он отображает:

```
Р”Р°СЂРѕРІР°
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Он загружает html код со всеми его разметками. Вам скорей всего надо задать `<head>` теги, а в них добавить `<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'>` и уж затем указанный вами текст...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вы-гений.Спасибо большое))

Comment: Давайте тогда закроем ответом...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebBrowser это по сути элемент, который читает HTML код. По стандартам HTML, сайт должен указывать кодировку в самой разметке (HTML), то есть он должен указать [HTTP charset](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index.ru) внутри тега `<head>`.

Исходя из этого, вам надо скорей всего задать до `<div>` тега что то вроде:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'>
</head>
```

Comment: Интересно сколько невалидных сайтов на просторах интернета,  полагаю много. В таком случаи приложение ТС окажется неработоспособным.

Comment: @DigitalCore Тут как я понял автор пишет что то свое на основе HTML, а не парсит сайт. Для серфа в интернете как по мне WebBrowser не подойдет, уж больно он старый и обрезанный. Ну а вообще, по сути все можно решить)